# Kubernetes service for background app

Tags: kubernetes

I'm in the middle of creating an K8s app that doesn't expose any HTTP endpoints, is just a background app that pulls messages from a message bus and takes some action based on the incoming message. No other apps will interact directly with this background app, only thru posting messages into the message bus.

Scaling is a requirement and most likely will always need to run more than one replica.  What is the recommended Service type in Kubernetes to handle this type of workload ?

Answer (score 4):

No service required... just create a Deployment, which will result in a ReplicaSet, which will keep *n* replicas of your app running.

Comment: IF you could help me on a bit more question around your answer - if its a background service with just doing some tasks with data from Db/message queues etc, we dont need to define what type of kind the k8 is? Just setup the deployment kind with replicas config? So what is it called when running in k8 - service/node/pod?